# ubuntu software center and snap availability, different versions

Tags: software-center, snap

Why are newer versions of snaps not available to run even after Ubuntu Software downloads newer versions?

Below is what snap list provides and attached are two screenshots from Ubuntu Software showing different versions

[image: two]

[image: screenshots]

```
$ snap list brave libreoffice
Name         Version      Rev  Tracking  Publisher  Notes
brave        v0.23.77dev  28   stable    brave      -
libreoffice  6.0.6.2      76   stable    canonical  -
```